# How to Store Files Locally in Sencha Touch2?

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

How to Store File in Offline in Sencha touch,,,

How to Use database i Sencha Touch Support Daatabase Connectivity?...

I use

```
 requires:['Ext.data.identifier.Uuid','Ext.data.proxy.Sql',],
    config: {

         identifier: {
    type: 'uuid'
},


      fields: [
         "firstName",
         "lastName",
         {
            name: "dateAdded",
            type: "date",
            defaultValue: new Date()
         }
      ],
      proxy: {
        type: "sql"
      }
    }
 });
```

Like this but error in **sql.js file not Found error...**

can any one Help me...

Comment: Did you try to use localstorage proxy instead of sql? Or do you need sql proxy?

Comment: i have to store one value and those values will work in offline also....that is my issue..

Comment: is localstorage proxy value will work offline?...

Comment: But local storage provides the ability to store data offline too. You can store about 5MB data offline in your browser

Comment: For example i have to download one book and store in Local Proxy and i can Use in offline right?...

Comment: how to use SQL Proxy?...

Comment: Yes. Have a look at http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32825/discussion-between-lukas-k-and-user1811486)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I understand

You normally store data via SQL Proxy (online), but you would like to manage to store data even if you are offline.

Fact is, I don't think you can use SQL to save data offline.

I think you will need to save data in Local Storage under a format you will "developt" and on App's opening and connection established read from that storage and force push an update from the local storage to the sql database.

The best I guess would to serialize you SQL data, save it to local storage, and unserialize when you can push it to the database.